# Refreshing a fragment in a tablayout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing an application in which I have used a tab layout, I want to refresh my fragment when I used to click on button. There is a counter on tab which shows number of users, but when I press the delete button, it delete that user but the counter remain same, to refresh it I have to again run that tab which is hard to do again and again. So is there any way to refresh it automatically with the counter value change.

Comment: You can use LiveData Concept.....
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 0):

I believe the tab is part of the parent activity and all other fragments are attached to it through a view pager. One of the easiest methods that you can do is write a callback to activity from fragment whenever the button is clicked and update the counter value. You can read more about it here: [Fragment Communication](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

Comment: Yes do you have any example through which this concept get more clear

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any sample code at the moment. But if you go through the docs it becomes pretty clear. You create an interface in fragment and attach it to the parent activity. There are tons of examples on the internet for reference and code samples

Comment: No problem.Just accept the answer as solution if it solved your problem